# ischecked on jquery not working for radio button

Tags: jquery

I want to check whether the question gets answered are not the is checked is working if the radio button selected for yes but for if user selects no the ischecked returns false. I dont know where i am doing wrong do any one help me please?
Below is my code..

```
<tr>
  <td>Is this application external user facing?</td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio"  name="genericQ3" id="genericQ3" value="YES"/>YES
    </br>
    <input type="radio" name="genericQ3" id="genericQ3" value="NO" />NO
   </td>
</tr>
```

jquery for this will be like below

```
if($("#genericQ"+i).attr("type")=="radio" && $("#genericQ"+i).is(":checked")){
  alert("radio button selected");
} else if ($("#genericQ"+i).attr("type")=="radio" && $("#genericQ"+i).is(":checked")==false {
  alert("radio button not selected");
}
```

when user selects no in radio button this jquery going to not selected but expecting it to be in radio selected.

Comment: `ischecked` works just fine. Duplicate IDs are what ruins everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the two radio buttons checked property like the following:

```
$('[name="genericQ3"]')[0].checked
```

Where the index 0 for Yes and 1 for No radio button.

Answer (score 0):

First off there was a syntax error with your code. Second make sure jQuery is included in your page. Third make sure you put all this inside `onload` event handler. In case you are using jquery, wrap the whole code inside

`$(function(){
    /** Your code here **/
});`

All of this in action here http://jsbin.com/qezogifa/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors in jQuery.

See http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/